# Image appears on text hover but it's in the wrong place

Tags: html, css

I have a pretty simple css code in which an image appears when I hover over certain text. It's working great in W3Schools where I'm editing it, but when I embed it into my website, the images are no longer appearing in the spot I've assigned.

Here is the code

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Lost Lovers;
  src: url(https://static.showit.co/file/Gjg1KacJSXuRotLMayqzvQ/118367/lostloversregular.woff);
}

div {
  font-family: Lost Lovers;
}

.services {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Lost Lovers;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: #f9c5ff;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
}

.services .services-top {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50;
  left: 70;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 120%;
}

.services:hover .services-top {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="services"> SERVICES <img src="https://static.showit.co/file/2Ke6sMvQT6qegFJ0rCoLcA/118367/chocbar.jpg" class="services-top" alt="Card Front"> </div>
```

And here is what it looks like on my website.
https://den-of-dreamers-34.showitpreview.com/new-page

I'm still playing around with where I want the image placed exactly, but no matter where I test it, it keeps appearing to the right of the text.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Did you expect it not to the be the right of the text when using an `display: inline;` on `:hover`?

Answer (score 1):

Specify units for your positioning:

```css
top: 50px; /* < -- add 'px' */
left: 70px; /* < -- add 'px' */
```